# Tricky question about generics, inheritance and chaining

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, lambda

For context - [read this](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/08/01/another-c-trick-fluents-inheritance-and-extension-methods.aspx).

Problem:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var b = new bar();

            b.buzz().fizz().buzz().fizz(); //cool
            //              ^FAIL!!!...<------------------------------------
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class foo
    {
        public foo fizz() { return this; }
    }

    public class bar : foo
    {
        public bar buzz()
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
```

Solution:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var b = new bar();

            b.buzz().fizz().buzz().fizz(); //cool stuff
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public static class fooExtensions
    {
        public static T fizz<T>(this T t) where T : foo
        { return t; } 
    }

    public class foo{}

    public class bar : foo
    {
        public bar buzz()
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
```

This is a technique how to 'mimic' method of base class which is able to return back derived type (otherwise my b couldn't call buzz() again).

Going further and making foo/bar generic (this will still work fine):

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var b = new bar<buzz>();

            b.buzz().fizz().buzz().fizz(); //cool
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static class fooExtensions
    {
        public static T fizz<T>(this T t) where T : foo<buzz>
        { return t; }
    }

    public class buzz { public string name { get; set;} }

    public class foo<T> where T : buzz
    {}

    public class bar<T> : foo<T> where T : buzz
    {
        public bar<T> buzz()
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
```

---

And the question is -
**how to pass lambda to `fizz` method that knows about `tbuzz` and it's properties without passing type parameter/s explicitly**.

Broken code that might reflect what i'm looking for:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var b = new bar<buzz>();

            b.buzz().fizz(x=>x.name).buzz().fizz(); //not cool anymore
            //               ^FAIL!!!<---------------------------------
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static class fooExtensions
    {
        //NO IDEAS WHAT TO WRITE BELOW!!!
        public static T fizz<T, Tbuzz>(this T t, 
            Func<Tbuzz, object> superlambda)
            where T : foo<buzz>
            where Tbuzz : buzz 
        {
            return t;
        }
    }

    public class buzz { public string name { get; set;} }

    public class foo<T> where T : buzz
    {}

    public class bar<T> : foo<T> where T : buzz
    {
        public bar<T> buzz()
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
```

Wondering if that's possible. And if not - why?

Theoretically - `foo<T>` knows that there's a `buzz` underneath.

Are there any other approach how to create base method or mimic it that supports chaining for such a classes?

Comment: Looks like the issue is with inferring type `Tbuzz` for `fizz<T, Tbuzz>`, which isn't connected at all with `foo<T>`. Out of curiosity, I tried changing the constraint on T to `where T : Foo<TBuzz>` to no avail.

Comment: As i wrote - those lines are broken. I understood that fizz<T, Tbuzz> is not connected too. Question is - can they be connected and if not - why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you're trying to accomplish is possible. Theoretically what you would need is some kind of constraint like:

```
where TBuzz : T<inner>
```

meaning TBuzz needs to be the type that's the inner generic type of T. This isn't possible as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

this?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = new bar();
        var a = b.buzz().fizz(x => x.name).buzz().fizz();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static class fooExtensions
{
    public static T fizz<T>(this T t) where T : foo
    { return t; }

    public static T fizz<T>(this T t,
        Func<T, object> superlambda)
        where T : foo
    {
        return t;
    }
}

public class foo { public string name { get; set; } }

public class bar : foo
{
    public bar buzz()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Not really. Foo is supposed to be generic. It should have type parameter that derives from buzz. And lambda should recognize buzz.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought I made progress with a kind of [Thrush combinator](http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2009/10/06/the-thrush-combinator-in-c)

```
public static T fizz<T>(this T t, Func<T, T> f)
{ return f(t); }
```

but that seems to be a dead end. Posting it anyway in case you can improve it.