# object doesn´t contain a definition for Id

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

**Error:**

> {"'object' does not contain a definition for 'Id'."}

**ViewModel**

```
public class PilotoVM
{
    private FormulaEntities1 db = new FormulaEntities1();

    public IQueryable<object> calcularValoracion()
    {
        return db.Piloto.GroupBy(p => p.id).Select(p => new { Id = p.Key, Valoracion = p.Sum( i=> i.agresividad + i.paciencia + i.reflejos + i.valentia + i.valentia)});
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.valoracion = pilotoVM.calcularValoracion();
    return View(piloto.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach (var pil in ViewBag.valoracion)
{
    <p>@pil.Id</p>
    <p>@pil.Valoracion</p>
}
```

Error in `pil.Id`

Comment: You're returning an anonymous type list to `IQueryable<object>`.  That's just begging for trouble.  You should be resolving to a collection of strongly typed objects.

Comment: It's not a good Idea return IQueryable to your controller, it's better to return a model  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215057/asp-mvc-should-services-return-iqueryables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `calcularValoracion()` returns an anonymous object. Anonymous types are internal and cant be accessed in the view (refer [this article](http://www.gregshackles.com/anonymous-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc-using-dynamics/) for a good explanation).

Instead, create a view model to represent you data

```
public class PilotoVM
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int Valoracion { get; set; }
}
```

then in the controller

```
List<PilotoVM> model = db.Piloto.GroupBy(p => p.id).Select(p => new PilotoVM()
{
  Id = p.Key, 
  Valoracion = p.Sum( i=> i.agresividad + i.paciencia + i.reflejos + i.valentia + i.valentia)
}).ToList();
```

Now you can return a strongly typed model to your view and access the propertues of each `PilotoVM` object in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should either create a strongly typed object representing your Id and Valoracian, or you could use a Tuple.

```
public List<Tuple<int, int>> calcularValoracion()
{
    return db.Piloto
        .GroupBy(p => p.id)
        .Select(p => new Tuple<int, int>(
            p.Key, 
            p.Sum(i => i.agresividad + i.paciencia + i.reflejos + i.valentia + i.valentia))
        .ToList();
}
```

View

```
@foreach (var pil in ViewBag.valoracion)
{
    @pil.Item1
    @pil.Item2
}
```

Note the `.ToList()` at the end of the query.  This resolve your query to an in memory collection so that you won't leak your context into your view.

Finally, method names in C# should be Pascal Cased, such as `CalcularValoracion()`.