# ASP.NET MVC2 with Entity Framework 4 - AsEnumerable() or ToList() in repository?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

So I've been advised a few times to disable lazy loading when building an application with the above frameworks, and that ToList() will force the queries in my repository to execute.  I was told that I would avoid certain "traps" I might run into if I used AsEnumerable().

On a recent question, however, I included a bunch of ToList()s in my code examples, and startled a number of people that assured me IEnumerable is much better to return.

I'm thoroughly confused now, to say the least.

Should I be returning IEnumerable in my repository, then converting them to List in my view models?  Should I use ToList() straightaway in my repository like I was before?  Was I suppose to leave deferred execution enabled in the first place?

Jiminy Christmas...

**Edit:**
So, being that I disabled lazy loading, based on earlier advice, should I then re-enable it, return IEnumerable / IQueryable from my repository, and convert the collection to a List in my view models, if needed?

One of the answers below associates IEnumerable with eager execution, while I was under the impression that only ToList() would force immediate execution of the query.

I stumbled across [this](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2009/01/should-my-repository-expose-iqueryable.html), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718624/to-return-iqueryablet-or-not-return-iqueryablet), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699607/asp-mvc-repository-that-reflects-iqueryable-but-not-linq-to-sql-ddd-how-to-ques/1699756#1699756) that all contain some interesting discussion related to this question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Call `ToList()`, returning an `IEnumerable` in your repository, if:

1. You want to control the output set provided to the consumer (i.e. you don't want them to run queries on it), and
2. You don't mind eager execution.

Return `IQueryable`, or `IEnumerable` via `AsEnumerable()`, in your repository if:

1. You don't mind your consumers running queries on the output set, and
2. You want deferred execution.

**See Also** 
http://thinkbeforecoding.com/post/2009/01/19/Repositories-and-IQueryable-the-paging-case

Comment: I suppose part of my question included whether or not I should be forcing eager execution with the given combination of frameworks, as some have advised.

Comment: In addition to the factors I've already mentioned, forcing eager execution may actually cause performance issues; the entire data set is returned in one go, even though the consumer might not actually need all of the data.

Comment: Interesting article.  Thank you.

Comment: You mentioned that disposing the context is something you never do?  Is my use of using() superfluous?

Comment: Aside from sorting and paging, `IQueryable<T>` allows you to project onto presentation models without worrying about loading strategies. It "just works".

Comment: I thought that if something implements `IQueryable<T>` and you return it as `IEnumerable<T>` the underlying object is still `IQueryable<T>` and therefore retains delayed execution etc...? Hence the reason to return `IList<T>`.

Comment: @Charlino: `IQueryable` inherits from `IEnumerable`, so no, an `IEnumerable` is not an `IQueryable`. However, see my edit.

Comment: I'm aware that `IEnumerable` isn't an `IQueryable` I was just pointing out that simply returning `IEnumerable` alone isn't enough. Your edit does clear it up, although I would add that `AsEnumerable()` isn't required seeings that `IQuerable` inherits from `IEnumerable` already.