# Custom functions on data Selected from IQueryable?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a database I'm trying to query via Entity Framework and then select the return data into an collection output object - while using `IQueryable` to improve performance - and then apply a couple functions to the resultant data that comes back from the DB query. For one, I can't use `.ToLocalTime()` on a `DateTime` object as it's not supported. I get this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime
>   ToLocalTime()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a
>   store expression.

If I try to call other custom functions on returned data I get a similar exception.

Here is my code below:

```
IQueryable<DatabaseEntityType> query = context.MyEntities.Where(c=> c.Finished == true);

db.MyEntities.OrderByDescending(c => c.DateCreated).Select(c => new OutputObject()
{
    Guid = c.Guid,
    Notes = c.Notes,
    DateCreated = c.DateCreated.ToLocalTime(),
    Related = String.Join("<br/>", c.RelatedEntities.Select(c => c.TractNumber)),
    Others = String.Join("<br/>", c.OtherRelatedEntities.Select(c => c.OwnerName)),
    DocumentType = EnumUtility.GetDocumentTypeString(c.DocumentType),
    Uploader = c.Account.FirstName + " " + c.Account.LastName,
});
```

Is there any way to do this while still using `IQueryable`? I have a large data set that needs to be filtered on the server without using a `.ToList()`.

Comment: You try AsEnumerable() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968469/whats-the-differences-between-tolist-asenumerable-asqueryable

Comment: Doesn't AsEnumerable fetch the entities just like ToList? Wouldn't help me if that's the case.

Comment: No. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775351/asp-net-mvc2-with-entity-framework-4-asenumerable-or-tolist-in-repository

Comment: From your code example it doesn't seem that you are using Date manipulation for filtering. If you can avoid it, I would leave the presentation code (making your results look pretty for display) to c#, not sql. And if you can't do that, make a View in sql and map that in EF.

Comment: I'd second @gunr2171's comment. Also, you generally can't just have any C# function running on the database server (which is what happens when your still using an `IQueryable`) -- it would have to be something that's translatable as it says. You could also use [DbFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx) or the [DbFunctionAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctionattribute(v=vs.113).aspx) if there's a specific function you want to use, though.

Comment: @gunr2171- I understand that I can't run C# code on the server. The issue is that I have another library that takes an IQueryable but I need to modify some of the return data from the SQL query before it goes into this other library. Any thoughts?

Comment: @jjj see my comment to gunr2171

Comment: Well, if the other library doesn't need to run stuff on the data source, you could use `AsEnumerable`, do your data manipulation, then use `AsQueryable` so that the library could be used. Of course, the entities would be loaded from the data source during the data manipulation.

Comment: Yeah it is Telerik UI for MVC and they have a DataSourceRequest object that comes back from the client... You then run a method on that object which directly queries the database via the IQueryable... I really need to be able to filter directly on the datasource. We're dealing with 10s of millions of rows.

Comment: You can read more about DataSourceRequest here in case I'm missing something http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq

Comment: Maybe you should add that to your question as well. I'm thinking there should be a way to use Telerik's library and still do the formatting you're trying to do after pulling data from the data source.